# List of dates of current and previous month in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, date

I want to have the dates of the current month and the previous month automatically get populated. So I'm using `=MONTH(NOW())` to get the current month and `=MONTH(NOW())-1` to get the previous month. Beneath them I'd like the dates to get listed just for that month. So for example it would look like this:

[image: 1]

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you want the dates to be automatically generated?

Comment: yes, automatically generated. So they get updated as the date/month changes.

Answer (score 1):

With the following formula you can construct a month table, containing all days of the month.

### Formula

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   DATE(
     YEAR(NOW()),                                                    // first
     A1,                                                             // second
     ROW(                                                            // third
       INDIRECT("A1:A" & DAY(EOMONTH(DATE(YEAR(NOW()), A1, 1), 0)))
     )   
   )
 )

 copy / past
 =ARRAYFORMULA(DATE(YEAR(NOW()),A1,ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A" & DAY(EOMONTH(DATE(YEAR(NOW()), A1, 1), 0))))))
```

### Screenshot

[image]

### Explained

The `DATE` formula is used to construct the date out of the three integers it needs. The first is the `YEAR`, being calculated from the `NOW` formula. The second argument is the month that you want to calculate the days from. The third argument must be a day number. Because we're using an `ARRAYFORMULA`, this is fed by a `ROW` range. The range of the rows, is dependent upon the amount of days per month. This number is calculated as follows:

```
DAY(                  // days
  EOMONTH(            // days till end of month in date notation
    DATE(
      YEAR(NOW()),    // from year 
      A1,             // from month
      1               // from day    
   )
 )
```

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[Days of Month](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JD_7UXXQ1GMbfs2WY3tRxh2SxfQ6pLe5mh0dOT93Wv8/edit?usp=sharing)**

Comment: You can change the formula, to reference a year number, as per @pnuts suggestion: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13056/conversation/list-of-dates

Answer (score 0):

- **cell A1:**

  ```
  ={MONTH(TODAY()); ARRAYFORMULA(TO_DATE(ROW(
    INDIRECT("A"&DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY()), 1)):
    INDIRECT("B"&EOMONTH(TODAY(), 0)))))}
  ```
- **cell B1:**

  ```
  ={MONTH(TODAY())-1; ARRAYFORMULA(TO_DATE(ROW(
    INDIRECT("A"&DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY())-1, 1)):
    INDIRECT("B"&EOMONTH(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY())-1, 1), 0)))))}
  ```

  [image]